# Subset data frame by factor cardinality?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I suspect that this will be a duplicate, but my efforts to find an answer have failed. Suppose that I have a data frame with columns made entirely of either integers or factors. Some of these columns have factors with many levels and some do not. Suppose that I want to select parts of or otherwise subset the data such that I only get the columns with factors that have less than 10 levels. How can I do this? My first thought was to make a particularly nasty `sapply` command, but I'm hoping for a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>%
    select_if(~ is.factor(.) && nlevels(.) < 10)
```

With a reproducible example using `iris`

```
data(iris)
iris %>%
       select_if(~ is.factor(.) && nlevels(.) < 10)
```

Or using `sapply`

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, function(x) is.factor(x) && nlevels(x) < 10)
df1[i1]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can do:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,.SD, .SDcols = sapply(df, function(x) length(levels(x))<10)]
```

## Example:

```r
df <- data.table(x = factor(1:3, levels = 1:5), y = factor(1:3, levels = 1:10))
df[,.SD, .SDcols = sapply(df, function(x) length(levels(x))>5)]
 y
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
```